# How to use "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always returns `false` in my ASP.NET Web API project.

In account `ApiController` I have following:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); 
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { 
    IsPersistent = isPersistent 
}, identity);
```

After signing in, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false` in `ApiController`
but `true` in MVC Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unable to use HttpContext property directly in APIControiller. To get this , you have to make use of Request property of type System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage. HttpRequestMessage has a Properties dictionary; you will find the value of the key MS_UserPrincipal holds your IPrincipal object.

Answer (score 7):

The [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Http.ApiController);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) has a **User** property and is available from:

```
base.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: please note that base.User can be null if not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

```
var isAusorized = (Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper).User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Comment: Care to explain what you did there?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.