# Authenticate WebAPI against AzureAD at the server boundary

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET 4.5 WebAPI application that uses "Integrated Windows Authentication" to authenticate against Active Directory. Every user in the local Active Directory is allowed to authenticate. Authentication is completely done outside the app, and I can access the current user principal via `ApiController.User`.

For a deployment in Azure App Services, I am trying to do mostly the same with Azure AD - using OAuth authentication to allow all users from a specific Azure AD tenant to login, which, as it seems, requires more than just a single line in WebConfig.

I have followed word-for-word the [Azure AD Quickstart](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/), until it came to the SignIn and SignOut functions: they only work with MVC and `Controller`, not with WebAPI and `ApiController`.

I have found that [ApiController works differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324141/how-to-use-user-identity-isauthenticated-in-web-api). But I am still stuck at a point where the `MS_UserPrincipal` property is not available from my ApiController.

[This tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) uses WebAPI and EntityFramework, but does not require authentication before the Api is started. Furthermore, it creates a user account database - in my case, Azure AD would be that database.

I have found that I can enforce a login requirement for all Controllers using

```
filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

in the Filter Config, but I am still neither forwarded to login nor does `MS_UserPrincipal` nor `ApiController.User` contain an AzureAD IPrincipal.

So, how would I implement an OAuth authentication requirement (against a specific tenant's Azure AD) for the whole application ("at the server boundary")?